# Fan runs when car is off?

Tags: cooling, mini-one

I have an 02 mini one and the fan stays on when switching off. Is this normal ? And  where do I top up the water please ? Thank you in advance x

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the radiator fan under the hood - these fans often run after a car is shut off so you're probably OK.

Also, see the red circle attached for a typical location for the coolant reservoir for a Mini One.

I highly recommend you refer to your owner's manual.

[image]

Comment: They run according to temperature , regardless of the ignition switch.

Comment: While you are correct about location for coolant reservoir, I'd be careful answering that without knowing **what** water the OP wants topped up...